# Docker build fails always with error hcsshim::PrepareLayer - failed failed in Win32: Incorrect function. (0x1) Windows Containers

Tags: docker-for-windows

Steps to reproduce are very easy.

Create a Dockerfile.

**My Dockerfile has many more lines, but I have trimmed them so we can focus in the source of the problem.**

**Said that, these two lines alone (without anything more) show the problem.**

```
FROM microsoft/iis
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'; "]
```

Run `docker build .` and you get `hcsshim::PrepareLayer - failed failed in Win32: Función incorrecta. (0x1)`.

Windows 10 Pro 1909 (but it happened too in 1903)

Docker version: 2.1.0.5

Engine: 19.03.5

Machine: 0.16.2

Comment: I tried with same version and its working for me

Comment: Only happens if you have an application that uses `cbfsconnect2017.sys`. Probably you don't have any application that uses it @Diego Baranowski

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem.

Reading all the https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884 bug, some have found a simple solution: rename `C:\windows\system32\driver\cbfsconnect2017.sys` so it isn't loaded the next boot.

Disabling that driver enables me to do a docker build for the first time in windows containers in almost a year.

In my case Box Sync was the one using that driver.

EDIT: @GustavoTM have found that pCloud raises the same problem.
EDIT2: @VonC have noticed that some people in the issue in GitHub has solved it deleting this other file: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\cbfs6.sys`. I haven't tried that, but i put it if it helps others.

The good thing is that I don't need to uninstall Box, but only rename that file.

Comment: After working for months without any problem with Docker for Windows, yesterday I decided to install a storage cloud application and I started to get this issue, after removing the application and renaming the file `cbfsconnect2017.sys` the issue disappeared. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Would be nice if you share which storage cloud application does that to prevent others to have the same problem @GustavoTM.

Comment: the cloud application was pCloud

Comment: See also, from https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884#issuecomment-694787557, deleting `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\cbfs6.sys`.

Comment: The same for me, Box Drive was using "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\cbfsconnect2017.sys" driver, deleted Box, deleted the driver and the problem

Comment: This worked for me. I just renamed cbfs6.sys and rebooted. However, I have to say that Docker or Microsoft need to do better here. This is a dreadful bug with an unacceptable workaround.

Comment: Pay attention, if you use Amazon Workdocs Drive it will stop working when you rename cbfsconnect2017.sys, see https://repost.aws/questions/QUlJQ4_taSTriGTehsFCmFjg/amazon-workdocs-drive-on-windows-always-returns-cannot-start-amazon-workdocs-drive-because-another-device-is-mounted-at-w

Comment: I was seeing this issue when executing `docker cp`, fixed it for me.

However, when running `docker commit` the command hangs. When stopping and when running again, I again see `Error response from daemon: hcsshim::UnprepareLayer failed in Win32: The system could not find the instance specified.` Has anyone seen/experienced similar behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This is still an [issue (still open) with Win10](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884).
Looks like uninstalling cloud storage providers with file system filters like Dropbox, Box, etc. as a workaround is an option for some users.

Deinstall cloud storage providers or virus scanners; if you identify which one is not working please share in https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884

Comment: I use several cloud drives (Google Drive, DropBox, Box and OneDrive).

Comment: I have tried to shutdown them and it seems it's not enough. Uninstalling them would be a problem for me now.

Comment: The whole idea behind docker is that it should avoid conflicts like this. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was the problem similar but the file `cbfs6.sys` was placed somewhere in the rest of uninstalled application Jungle disk, somewhere in the folder `c:\Program files\Jungle disk ...`. It's part of Callback File System signed by EldoS Corporation.

The folder could be rename only and not delete directly. So I could delete its immediately after the PC restart, before running the Docker. So it could be delete during the Docker service restart too.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the driver "cbfsconnect2017.sys" which map an NT disk from SFTP.
When I have stopped the mapping tool (SFTP Net Drive 2017) the problem was disappear ;)
Thanks for all contributors

Comment: Please try to correct the tenses when answering. Thank you.